# Find $\angle CAD$ in following figure.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

[image]

> In $\triangle ABC$, $\angle ACB =20°$ and $\angle CAB = \angle CBA=80°$
>
> $D$ is a point on $CB$ such that $CD=AB$
>
> Find $\angle CAD$

I assumed $\angle CAD=\theta$ and $AB=CD=x$

Applying sine rule in $\triangle CAD$ and $\triangle ABD$

$$\frac {x} {\sin\theta}=\frac {AD} {\sin 20^\circ}$$

$$\frac {x} {\sin(\theta+20°)}=\frac {AD} {\sin 80^\circ}$$

So,

$$\frac {\sin(\theta+20)} {\sin\theta}=\frac {\sin 80^\circ} {\sin 20^\circ}=\frac {1} {2\sin 10^\circ}$$

I don't think this equation for $\theta$ can be solved without using calculator.
If anyone can solve it, please show me the method. (Please do not guess.)

If not solvable, then please provide me any other solution. (If the solution is pure geometric and contains   construction, then please also tell me  your intuition behind your construction.)

Comment: Please tell if the image can be opened.

Comment: The image says "access denied" Edit: I still cannot access it.

Comment: Are you able to see it now?

Comment: I don't get it. If D is on segment AC and you are asking the angle CAD? These points are collinear. Am I missing something?

Comment: See the solutions here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToLong.shtml

Comment: Dear Aretino, thanks for giving this link, but I need something other than solution.

Comment: If you write $\frac 12$ as $\sin 30^\circ=\sin(10^\circ+20^\circ$, all you need to show is that $\theta=10^\circ$ is unique solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continue by solving the equation

$$\frac {\sin(\theta+20^\circ)} {\sin\theta}=\frac {1} {2\sin 10^\circ}.$$

as follows

\begin{align}
\cot \theta & = \frac1{2\sin 10^\circ\sin 20^\circ}-\cot 20^\circ 
= \frac{\sin(10^\circ+ 20^\circ)}{\sin 10^\circ\sin 20^\circ}-\cot 20^\circ 
=\cot 10^\circ
\end{align}

Thus, $\theta = 10^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=AB, b=BD, \alpha=∠BDA, \beta=∠BAD$
$b = CB - CD = {a/2 \over \sin(10°)} - a$

For ΔABD, we now have SAS, and use **Law of Tangents**:
$${a+b \over a-b} = {\tan{\alpha+\beta \over 2} \over \tan{\alpha-\beta \over 2}}$$
$$ {1 \over 4\sin(10°)-1} =  {\tan{50°} \over \tan{\alpha-\beta \over 2}}$$
$\begin{align} \tan{\alpha-\beta \over 2} 
&= (4\sin(10°)-1) \tan(50°) \cr
&= {4\sin(10°)\sin(50°) - \sin(50°) \over \cos(50°) }\cr
&= {2\cos(40°) - 2\cos(60°) - \cos(40°) \over \sin(40°)}\cr
&= {\cos(40°) - 1  \over \sin(40°)}\cr
&= {-2\sin^2(20°)  \over 2\sin(20°)\cos(20°)}\cr
&= \tan(-20°)
\end{align}$
$$\beta = {\alpha+\beta \over 2} - {\alpha-\beta \over 2} = 50° + 20° = 70°$$
$$ ∠CAD = ∠CAB - \beta = 80° - 70° = 10° $$